# Rails: Rendering a Namespaced Polymorphic Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, namespaces, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic model called `Update`. Typically, I can render its associated `updatable` model with a simple:

```
<%= render @update.updatable %>
```

Unfortunately, if I'm calling this method from within a namespaced controller, then Rails will try to namespace the view path as well, searching `admin/reviews/review` rather than `reviews/review`. This results in errors like:

```
Missing partial admin/reviews/review
```

Typically I can hardcode a workaround, such as:

```
<%= render :partial => "/reviews/review", :locals => {:review => @update.updatable}
```

This would be fine if the association weren't polymorphic, but since it is, I'll get errors if the `updatable` is anything other than a `Review`. Unfortunately, I have dozens of possible `updatable`s, and branching through them with a `case` statement would be troublesome to maintain.

Is there a simpler approach I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define the partial path from your models. It is something like this:

```
class Review
  def to_partial_path
    "/reviews/review"
  end
end
```